# Fancybox Images and Video in same Gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, markup

I'm using fancy box for my pop-up gallery but I'm having a problem. I want to have images and videos in the same gallery. I have a thumbnail that shows different work in my portfolio and we are a design and video firm so its essential that I'm have the ability to do both in the same pop-up-gallery. Has anyone else ran into this problem before? I'd imagine it's pretty common for people to want to do this.

Here is my mark up...I have the same rel attribute so they are in the same gallery but I'm calling a different script so that the type can be properly set.

```
$("a#brianguehring").fancybox();

$("a#brianguehring-video").fancybox({ 
    'type'          : 'swf',
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
});

<span>
<a class="grouped_elements icon_camera" rel="group-brian" id="brianguehring" title="Brian Guehring Website" href="images/portfolio/brianguehring-one.png"></a>
</span>

<span>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group-brian" id="brianguehring-video" title="Pasquale Vitello'Showreel 2010" href="http://vimeo.com/24081323">&nbsp;</a>
</span>
```

Comment: what version of fancybox? I think your approach is correct however you might be missing some elements in your script, for instance I don't think you should set `'type':'swf'` for your videos but `'iframe'` instead. You may also need to change the URL like the one provided in the `embed` code from vimeo site like `http://player.vimeo.com/video/24081323?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0` etc. Last, try to use classes instead of ID so you can re-use the same code on several elements in your code.

Answer (score 5):

Here I have got it working. I assume you want the image and the video in the same group. 
I put the working example here on JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4pAQz/1/

Your JS call would look like this. And it all has to be in one call.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'titlePosition'     : 'over',
    'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
        return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' +  (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + ' ' + title + '</span>';
    }
});
});
```

Your HTML would look like this:  NOTICE: notice that the href for the Vimeo player is the player.vimeo.com/video/YourIDHere. No need for the SWF code. It just works.  You also need both anchor rel="" to be the same name so the objects are put into the same group.

```
<div>
 <a rel="example_group" title="Custom title" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930.jpg">
 <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2641/4163443812_df0b200930_m.jpg" />
 </a>
 <a rel="example_group" title="Title of video here" class="various iframe" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/24081323?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0">
 <img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2591/4135665747_3091966c91_m.jpg" />
 </a></div>
```

Comment: After adding 'type' : 'swf', I'm still only getting a blank video that pops-up and doesn't actually play. Is there a reason for that? http://2012.delineamultimedia.com/ -> I'm working with the top 2 images.

Comment: The JS Fiddle link you sent isn't working for me, I tried clearing my cache but that didn't do it.

Comment: hmm JS Fiddle link it self isn't working? or the example isn't working. I just tried it and it worked.  It looks like you have your example working on your demo site.  There is an issue with the over spot for the arrow on the left is covering the play button for the Vimeo play button.  You may want to overtake some of the CSS for the hoverable area of the arrow of the FancyBox.

Comment: I see JS fiddle is actually messing up. Copy and paste the full HTML to a blank HTML page and run it locally on your computer. That should work.  But still the arrows are messing blocking the play button and embed box. Just the hoverable area. That can be fixed with overtaking the CSS. Also, try using player.vimeo.com URL instead like this "http://player.vimeo.com/video/24081323?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0".  If you do it that way, you don't need the type: option.